# Lotus Notes Scheduled agent failed to open database in different server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a database in server 1 which refers to multiple databases in server 2 for record validation purposes. When the scheduled agent runs, it encounters an "Object Variable not set" error. However, when I tried to manually run the agent (Right click agent name, click Run) it runs smoothly without error.

I simulated the database setup in 2 virtual servers and was able to reproduce the error. Line by line debugging shows that the error occurred when it tries to open the database in the other server. Since manual run works smoothly, I do not think the code or variables (server & database path) is wrong.

I've check the ACL for all databases to include the signer and server, also tried to schedule run the agent in all 3 security modes (Restricted, Unrestricted and Restricted with Admin Right). I've looked into the server document and security and allowed access to and from both servers. Anything else that I may have missed?

Comment: Are your servers in the same domain? Is there any code in your agent which forces a recompile at runtime? For example Evalute().

Comment: Both servers are in the same domain. The Object variable not found occurred on the line where it tries to open the database from the other server using the command If Not (dbname).Isopen.

Comment: Might need to put up a small sample. The error relates to dbname not being initialised.

Answer (score 7):

Let's call the server where the agent runs "server1", and the server where the database is stored "server2".  The problem is that the agent is running under the identity of the user that signed it, and server1 has verified that signature, but server2 has not.  Server2 needs to know the signature so that it can enforce the ACL on the database, so server2 must get the signature information from server1.  But server1 could theoretically lie to server2, so by default server2 does not trust signature information from server1.

Fortunately, there is a way to tell server2 to trust the signatures on agents that are running on server1.  In the Server Document for server2 in the Domino Directory on server2, go to the Security tab, and find the field labeled "Trusted Servers".  Enter server1's fully qualified name in this field, and restart server2.  (I'm not sure if the restart is really needed.)

That should allow your agent on server1 to read databases on server2.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let u know how it goes.

Comment: That would only apply if the servers are in different domains.

Comment: Simon, with respect, I'd be surprised if that's true. I know for sure that prior to R6, an agent could never access a database on another server, even in the same domain. The trusted server permission was created to allow it. I had a long discussion with Charlie Kaufman (lead security architect of Domino at the time) to discuss what the trust implied. If it were automatic within the domain, then any user with ability to create agents on 1 server in the domain would be able to get access databases on other servers even if the user is not listed in the Access Servers field for those servers.

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation. Consider server1 & server2 in the same domain. User1 has access to server1 and can create agents.  User1 is not in the Access Server list for server2.  User1 creates an agent on server1 and the agent opens foo.nsf on server2.  This database has ACL default = Reader, relying on the restrictive Access Server list to keep others out.  (Stupid, but it should work.) The agent runs on server1, and it opens a session to server2.  Although the agent is signed by user1, server1 uses its own ID file to connect - because it doesn't have user1's id file.

Comment: Server2 checks it's Allow Access list and finds server1, so we're past that barrier.  Now, the agent manager code in server1 knows that the agent is running on behalf of user1, so it when it wants to open a remote database it calls NSFDbOpenExtended and passes in the optional hNames argument, which points to the name used in the agent signature.  Sever2 checks this name against the database ACL -- but not against the Access Server list because we're already past that. So voila! Security has been bypassed.

Comment: So the idea is that trusted server should be granted only when you're okay with not having a particular server be able to present it's own id for server access, but then present another user's name for database access.  It would really surprise me if they've made trusting all servers in the domain the default, particularly since there's no way to take it away.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. Adding server 1 to the Trusted Server list in server 2 solves the issue. I assumed that if the agent signer is in the ACL of database to be accessed and provided the server and database path variable are correct, there would be no problem opening the database from a different server. Apparently the server access needs to be configured as well. So is it correct that now that server 1 is in the Trusted Server list of server 2, any other agents in any other database in server 1 can access databases in server 2?

Comment: There is also the question of manually running the agent prior to adding server 1 to the Trusted Servers list in server 2 yields the expected and correct outcome. Is there a different server access used when running an agent manually vs scheduling the agent? If it is not too troublesome pls explain.

Comment: Right-clicking and selecting "Run" does not run the agent on server1.  It runs the agent within Domino Designer on your own computer, so no special trust is required.  When you run it that way, the connection to server2 is authenticated using your ID file -- which is impossible when you actually run the agent on the server.

Comment: Re "So is it correct that now that server 1 is in the Trusted Server list of server 2, any other agents in any other database in server 1 can access databases in server 2?"  Yes, it is correct -- as long as the signers of the other agents have access in the ACLs of the databases that they are trying to open.

Comment: I stand corrected. :) Also took a while to dig out the documentation (may need to update infocenter). Details: "Enter the names of servers that are trusted to assert the identities of users to this server, and thus are trusted by the current server to have authenticated those users."