# Java Notes API: Create Client Session with Domino Libraries

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to use the Notes Java API over a local Domino server using a client User ID file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a client or server id for client code, but I'm not entirely sure that what you're asking will work.  I realize it's not your question, but I think your better approach is to resolve the "You are not listed as a trusted server" error.  For that, there's this:

[Lotus Notes Scheduled agent failed to open database in different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680242/lotus-notes-scheduled-agent-failed-to-open-database-in-different-server)

because the client shouldn't care whether the server is 32 or 64 bit.  Or PC/Midrange/Mainframe.

Comment: That is correct. When the APIs run on a server platform, regardless of whether it is a 32 bit or 64 bit server platform, they will run with the server's credentials. That would allow the code to have all the privileges that are granted to the server itself when talking to other servers, and IBM wants to limit the ability of an exploit on one server to gain access to other servers. The "Trusted Server" setting is necessary in order to get around this. Note: it is the server you are accessing that must trust the server you are running on.